# How do I start my VirtualBox machine on login?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, boot

I have a Linux host with a Windows XP guest machine.
I need that Windows XP machine starts after the user does login on Linux. So, how do I start my VirtualBox machine on login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your startup applications (assuming you've got something with the Gnome desktop environment, you didn't say wich distro you're using): `virtualbox --startvm <name>`, replacing `<name>` by the name of the virtual machine you'd like to start.

Comment: using the headless option might be useful too, depending on how he accesses the VM

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a linux logon script. Maybe in bash. Here is a post of a guy doing it in slackware with virtual box.

[Virtual Box Forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=16401&sid=1a3489bdb67f1ad0a0366be569932be8)